# How to get selected menu item in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

In my program, I have a context menu that has an Insert submenu. Instead of making a different function for each option in the submenu, I would like to bind all the options to the same function. Is there a way for me to determine the label or id of the selected item so that I can pass it to a different function?

EDIT: After a bit of research, I found the function GetId(), which is what I wanted, but I still need to get the label from the id. I might be able to use FindWindowById, which is a function of wx.Window, but it only looks through the children of the window. The frame doesn't appear to be a parent of the items in the submenu, so I can't just do `frame.FindWindowById(id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use partial to send an option (some unique ID) to a common function.  If you have a lot of menu items, use a for() loop, store the return in a list (instead of menu_item_x), and increment a counter to send to the function.

```
import wx
from functools import partial

class MenuCallback(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        self.frame=wx.Frame(None)
        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu1 = wx.Menu()
        menu_item_1 = menu1.Append(-1, "&Option #1")
        menu_item_2 = menu1.Append(-1, "&Option #2")
        menu_item_3 = menu1.Append(-1, "&Exit...")

        menu_bar.Append(menu1, "&File")
        self.frame.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)
        self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, partial(self.option_chosen, 1),
                        menu_item_1)
        self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, partial(self.option_chosen, 2),
                        menu_item_2)
        self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_close, menu_item_3)

        self.frame.Show(True)

    def option_chosen(self, number, event):
        print "option chosen =", number

    def on_close(self, event):
        self.frame.Close(True)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
MC=MenuCallback(parent=None, id=-1)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Just an FYI that `wx.PySimpleApp` is deprecated. I don't think it will be available in wxPython Phoenix.

Answer (score 4):

Having offered a solution to your question, I realised that there should be another way of implementing my solution. In fact there is and I may adopt this myself, as it is cleaner and uses less memory. This uses the `event.GetEventObject()` method.

```
import wx

class MenuCallback(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.frame=wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
#        self.statusbar = wx.StatusBar(self-1)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("Demonstration of wxPython")
        menu1 = wx.Menu()
        menu_item_1 = menu1.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&File")
        menu_item_2 = menu1.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Exit...")
    #Build a list of things via another function or just a declaration
        self.list_of_things = ["Thing No 1", "Thing No 2", "Thing No 3"]
        list_used = wx.Menu()
        thing_count = 101

        for thing in self.list_of_things:
            t1 = wx.MenuItem(list_used, thing_count, thing)
            list_used.AppendItem(t1)
            thing_count +=1

        thing_end = wx.MenuItem(list_used,199,'End of List')
        list_used.AppendItem(thing_end)

        menu1.AppendMenu(wx.ID_FILE,'&Things',list_used)
        menu1.SetHelpString(wx.ID_FILE, 'Select from the list of things')

        self.menubar.Append(menu1, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)
    # Create bindings for the Thing list
        i_count = 101
        for i in self.list_of_things:
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnThingOpen, id=i_count)
            i_count = i_count + 1
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnThingEnd, id=199)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnClose, id=wx.ID_EXIT)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnThingOpen(self, event):
        id_selected = event.GetId()
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        print "Option =", id_selected
        print obj.GetLabel(id_selected)
        print "From the range:"
        for i in range(obj.MenuItemCount):
            print "\t\t", obj.MenuItems[i].GetLabel()

    def OnThingEnd(self, event):
        pass

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    MC=MenuCallback(parent=None, id=-1)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be pretty but I find it effective to use a list with a menu Id range. Not only is it easy to understand but it is also flexible, like so:

```py
import wx

class MenuCallback(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.frame=wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu1 = wx.Menu()
        menu_item_1 = menu1.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&File")
        menu_item_2 = menu1.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "&Exit...")
    #Build a list of things via another function or just a declaration
        self.list_of_things = ["Thing No 1", "Thing No 2", "Thing No 3"]
        list_used = wx.Menu()
        thing_count = 101

        for thing in self.list_of_things:
            t1 = wx.MenuItem(list_used, thing_count, thing)
            list_used.AppendItem(t1)
            thing_count +=1

        thing_end = wx.MenuItem(list_used,199,'End of List')
        list_used.AppendItem(thing_end)

        menu1.AppendMenu(wx.ID_FILE,'&Things',list_used)
        self.menubar.Append(menu1, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)
    # Create bindings for the Thing list
        i_count = 101
        for i in self.list_of_things:
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnThingOpen, id=i_count)
            i_count = i_count + 1
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnThingEnd, id=199)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnClose, id=wx.ID_EXIT)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnThingOpen(self, event):
        id_index = 101
        id_selected = event.GetId()
        id_selected = id_selected - id_index
        print "Option =", id_selected
        print "Thing selected =", str(self.list_of_things[id_selected])

    def OnThingEnd(self, event):
        id_selected = event.GetId()
        print "Option =", id_selected

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        MC=MenuCallback(parent=None, id=-1)
        app.MainLoop()
```